# Caso de uso em Ferramenta Case

Tags: java, modelagem, uml

como devemo criar os diagramas de caso de uso, faço um diagrama englobando todos os casos de uso ou faço vários diagramas para cada cenário específico.

Ex.: Tenho dentro do sistema várias linhas de trabalho, parte de estoque, parte financeira, parte de venda para clientes. 
Eu crio diagramas com todos os casos de uso tudo misturado ou faço um para estoque, faço outro diagrama só para financeiro e ai por diante?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui não é o lugar mais apropriado para tratar desse assunto especificamente, porque da forma como foi posto se tornaria muito amplo, mesmo sendo um assunto muito importante.

Você pode usar [**sites como o UFCG**](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~sampaio/cursos/2007.1/Graduacao/SI-II/Uml/diagramas/usecases/usecases.htm).

Caso você crie seus casos de uso e sinta alguma dúvida em relação a eles, você poderá elaborar essa dúvida específica e postá-la aqui.

A questão dos casos de uso é que você tem que considerar os atores, que são os usuários do sistema.

O centro do sistema devem ser os usuários, então, os seus casos de uso, sejam em formato de planilha ou de diagramas, devem considerar quais ações cada ator deve realizar e isso **deve ser exaustivo**, isto é, você deve descrever todos os casos de uso para todos os usuários ou atores.

Na verdade, como parte inicial do processo de elicitação de requisitos, os casos de uso descrevem as funcionalidades do sistema sucintamente. Desta forma, cada ator de estar ligado a pelo menos uma ação e uma ação a pelo menos um ator, de forma que detalhes que serão tratados mais adiante no processo de elicitação de requisitos não estejam presentes. É uma espécie de visão geral do sistema, tão geral, que pela falta de detalhes é chamada, esta parte do processo de engenharia de software, de **caixa-preta**.

Isso é literalmente assunto para mais de um livro. [Engenharia de Requisitos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_requisitos) é onde tudo começa. Pesquisa pelas necessidades é o que vai dar origem aos primeiros modelos do software, então, todas as ações que cada ator deve e pode realizar no sistema devem ser explicitadas nos casos de uso de forma simples. (Exemplo: Ator: Funcionário RH -> Registrar férias - e todas as outras ações que esse funcionário pode realizar).

Comment: Obrigado!!!
Cara, abusando do seu conhecimento e da sua ajuda, cabe colocar o texto do caso de uso junto do diagrama de caso de uso?